# SAS format to convert country codes to country names

Tags: sas

Is there a SAS 9.4 out of the box way to convert a country code to a country name?
There could be a SAS format or a sashelp dataset that contains this information.

Example:

```
'AF'  -- > 'Afghanistan'
'AL'  -- > 'Albania'
```

Sashelp.demographics contains the Country Code but not the country alphanumeric code.

The SAS Visual Analytics lookup Values for country codes for Maps are close to what I want, but I am looking for something out of the box that I can call from base SAS.

http://support.sas.com/rnd/datavisualization/va63geo/VA63LookupValues.html

Any ideas on whether I can get this lookup table or format out of the box?

Comment: As an alternative to Joe's answer, please also see [Two letter country codes in SAS PROC FORMAT](http://heuristicandrew.blogspot.com/2016/02/iso-3166-1-alpha-2-two-letter-country-code-sas.html ). Maybe this fits better into your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS 9.4 has a new set of maps, the GFK maps, which has a dataset that contains information similar to what you expect.

`MAPSGFK.WORLD_ATTR` has the country name, upcased country name, 2 letter alpha, ISO 2 letter alpha, ISO 3 letter alpha, and ISO country code for each country in its list (250 in total).

Comment: Do you need SAS/Graph to get those or not?  I'm guessing no because it looks like they're separate from the maps that are in SASHELP...

Comment: I don't think you need SAS/GRAPH for them.  They were added in 9.4 as one of the improvements there, and SAS/GRAPH is quite old and not being improved anymore.

Comment: Just checking.  Yeah I won't be sad to see SAS/Graph disappear.  I for one welcome our new GTL overlords...